# Stripe API's Delete Coupon Request is not working properly for NodeJs

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I am trying to integrate coupons for stripe. But getting a weird error.

**Error Description:**

When I used to call delete from the file in which it is created it started working but when I used to call in another module after exporting it gives no coupon exist with error code **`"resource_missing"`**.

**Following is my source code**

```
const stripe = require('stripe')('API_SECRET_KEY');

createCoupon = async (couponId,percentOff, duration, durationInMonths) => {
    const coupon = await stripe.coupons.create({
    id:couponId,
    percent_off: percentOff,
    duration: duration,
    duration_in_months: durationInMonths,
    }).then(
        function(result){
            return console.log(result);
        },
        function(err) {
            if(err.raw.code == "resource_already_exists"){
                return console.log({"code": "coupon_already_exists"});
            } 
            else {
                return console.log({"code": "invalid_request"});
            }
        }
    );
    console.log(coupon);
};

getCoupon = async (couponId) => {
    const coupon = await stripe.coupons.retrieve(
        couponId
    ).then(
        function(result){
            return console.log(result);
        },
        function(err) {

            console.log(err.raw.code)
            if(err.raw.code == "resource_missing"){
                return console.log({"code": "no_such_coupon"});
            } 
            else {
                return console.log({"code": "invalid_request"});
            }
        }
    ); 

}

deleteCoupon = async (couponId) => {
    const deletedCoupon = await stripe.coupons.del(
        couponId
    ).then(
        function(result){
            console.log(result);
        },
        function(err) {
            if(err.raw.code == "resource_missing") {
                return console.log({"code": "no_such_coupon"});
            }
            else {
                return console.log({"code": "invalid_request"});
            }
        }
    );
};


// createCoupon("50_off", "50", 'repeating', "4");
// getCoupon("50_off");
deleteCoupon("50_off");
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that you're not deleting a Coupon twice? I'd suggest checking you logs in the Stripe Dashboard to confirm all of your calls. Also, if you're using Connect and trying to apply a Coupon from one account, you need to make sure you're using the same Account as the Coupon was created on.

Comment: Thanks for guiding. I checked the dashboard and there were 44% errors only for delete requests. I didn't change a single line even and code started running. Its weired